# Julia: Functional Programming :Validate array entries against another array of values

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, julia, higher-order-functions

I'm tying to create a one liner that filters an array against an array of values. Meaning that I want to cycle through each element of A and compare to the elements of B.

For example: What is safe to drink?

```
A = ["water";"beer";"ammonia";"bleach";"lemonade"]
B = ["water";"beer"; "lemonade"]
```

I slapped together this monstrosity but, I'm hoping someone has a more elegant approach:

```
julia> vcat(filter(w->length(w)!= 0, map(y->filter(z->z!="",(map(x-> begin x==y ? x = y : x = ""  end,B))),A))...)
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "water"
 "beer"    
 "lemonade"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.filter) to iterate over the available drinks and [`in`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.in) to check whether the current element is in the list of safe drinks:

```
julia> drinks = ["water", "beer", "bleach"];

julia> safe = ["beer", "lemonade", "water"];

julia> filter(in(safe), drinks)
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "water"
 "beer"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` approach is very neat. You can also use a comprehension:

```
[a for a in A if a in B]
```